# Configure proxy by IP adress in Karate

Tags: proxy, ip, karate

I am using Karate to tests some APIs.
I created a script which loops over a set of urls to be tested, but for some of them I need to pass through a proxy of which I have only the ip address.
I saw that in Karate there is the possibility to set up some proxy configuration, but I found guides in which it is used the  normal https address.

Does someone know if it is possible to configure the proxy using the ip address?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: should it not work if you prepend `http://` to the IP that you have ?